# Error:Invalid <arg> tag: turtlebot_description

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I am beginner in ROS and Turtlebot3 and I'm trying to run this command line `roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_remote.launch` to launch robot state publisher and I have this error:

```
while processing /home/fish/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_bringup/launch/includes/description.launch.xml:
Invalid <arg> tag: turtlebot3_description
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/fish/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share. 

Arg xml is <arg default="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro'" name="urdf_file"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

It looks like I do not have urdf file

Please help!

Ubuntu Xenial
ROS version: Kinetic
Tutorial: http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/bringup/#load-a-turtlebot3-on-rviz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329651/error:invalid-%3Carg%3E-tag:-turtlebot_description/) by [fish24](https://answers.ros.org/users/44269/fish24/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to solve it. I have reinstalled turtlebot3 packages on my PC, and then delete the folder.

Link to turtlebot3 repository: https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3.git

How to install using git clone:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src

git clone <link>

cd ~/catkin_ws

catkin_make
```

---

Originally posted by [fish24](https://answers.ros.org/users/44269/fish24/) with karma: 28 on 2019-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1